# Saving changes from a custom component in React-Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, react-codemirror

How do I save the output of a custom component back into the React Admin model?

I have a form with one custom component, which is a CodeMirror field.  The changes to everything else save properly.  But my CodeMirror field, while working properly as an editor and configured as I want, doesn't save changes.

I'm brand new to React-Admin, and only have limited experience with React, so I imagine I'm missing something basic.

```js
const handleChange = (field) => (val, evt) => {
  // I reach here with `field` set to the instance of MyEditField, with `val`
  // set to the updated editor value, and `evt` the CodeMirror event

  // But now how do I update the underlying record?

  // The following will update the stored copy, but doesn't mark it as a change 
  // to be saved by the dataProvider.   (And I know it doesn't make sense with Redux.)

  field.props.record.myField = val;
}

class MyEditField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.value = beautify(props.record[props.source]);

    // CodeMirror setup

    this.options = {/* CodeMirror options */}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CodeMirror 
        ref="CodeMirror" 
        value={this.value} 
        onChange={handleChange(this)} 
        options={this.options}
      />
    )
  }  
}

export default addField(MyEditField)
```

I highlight `handleChange` here not because I think that's where I think the change belongs, but only to demonstrate that if I need a place to hang the right code, I have one.  An `onBlur` would probably be better.  The point there is that I do have a way to run whatever code I need with access to my field and to the CodeMirror instance.

(The curried version of `handleChange` seems slightly strange but was necessary because some combination of the CodeMirror wrapper I'm using and React-Admin seemed to be losing my `this` reference, even if I used `bind(this)`.  But I enter that function with `field` correctly set, so this works.)

Everything seems correct with CodeMirror here.  I think I just need to know how to make the change reflect properly.

I don't think know if it's relevant, but I'm using the [React CodeMirror Wrapper](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-codemirror).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component)

You need to call the `onChange` function from redux-form `input` with your new value. This `input` is a prop react-admin injects to your component.

The same is true for reading the value by the way. Don't check the record as it will only ever be the initial record. Use the `input.value`.

Something like:

```
const MyEditField = ({ input }) => (
    <CodeMirror 
        ref="CodeMirror" 
        value={beautify(input.value)} 
        onChange={val => input.onChange(val)} 
        options={{
            // Options
        }}
    />
)

export default addField(MyEditField)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've been using RA to great success except for this issue, which drove me crazy for days.  BTW I don't see anything in that section of the docs about `onChange`.  It's probably some baseline knowledge which I'm still missing, but it really did stump me, even as I read and re-read that section.  (And I'm quite impressed with those docs overall.  I simply couldn't find this.)  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, we don't cover how react, redux or redux-form work. You'll have to check their documentation. Glad you appreciate our docs :)